# How to store the contents of a dictionary in a table using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dictionary with the following format:

```
{'one': {
    'two': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    'three': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'four': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
 'five': {
    'six': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    'seven': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    'eight': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    'nine': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]}}
```

How to use pandas in python The format of this dictionary when put into an excel sheet looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What does the expected output look like?

Comment: The table above is the expected output

Comment: one five    
two         0 0 0 0 1 
three 0 0 0 0 0 
four         0 0 0 0 0 
six         0 0 0 0 0 1
seven 0 0 0 0 1 0
eight 1 0 0 0 0 0
nine     0 0 0 1 0 0
I tried what you said and the results are as shown above and it doesn't do what I want

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your dictionary is called `dct`:

```
pd.concat({k:pd.DataFrame(d).T for k,d in dct.items()})
```

Or slightly better:

```
pd.concat({k:pd.DataFrame(d) for k,d in dct.items()}, axis=1).T
```

Output:

```
            0  1  2  3  4    5
one  two    0  0  0  0  1  NaN
     three  0  0  0  0  0  NaN
     four   0  0  0  0  0  NaN
five six    0  0  0  0  0  1.0
     seven  0  0  0  0  1  0.0
     eight  1  0  0  0  0  0.0
     nine   0  0  0  1  0  0.0
```